# How can I specify attributes to use in update_attributes in ROR3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, orm

What I'm trying to achieve is to update only accessible attributes in my Order model passing a current_user object like this:

```
  order.update_attributes(current_user.attributes.ONLY(:name, :surname, :email))
```

So is it possible to achieve this without explicitly setting columns to update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Hash#slice](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/Slice.html) from Rails:

`current_user.attributes.slice(:name, :surname, :email)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Hash#select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-select), like in following example:

```
current_user.attributes.select{|key, _| [:name, surname, email].include?(key)}
```